# How to prevent users from altering the BIOS?

Tags: bios, updates

I have a computer that I'd like have people be able to remotely access. The motherboard is a ASUS WRX80e-sage.

I have a lot of other considerations, but I'd like to start here. I want to make sure a user who is logged in remotely cannot alter the BIOS. The user will have admin access in windows, so they'll be able to run anything they want, adjust settings, group policies, etc… Meaning locking it down in the OS isn't an option.

I'm hoping that there is something in the BIOS that allows me to lock it down from being altered outside of the BIOS itself.

When I Google it, all that shows up is how to prevent Windows updates from doing it. I want it to prevent that, but I also want to make sure a user cannot run a utility or something that will do that as well.

There is a setting or something in the BIOS that locks it down from outside changes? I'm open to other ideas as well.

Comment: Does your BIOS allow adding a BIOS password? If you set this, are you prompted to enter the BIOS password in order to run BIOS updating/modifying software in the OS? I would guess that this is the correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: Remote users cannot access the firmware (UEFI or old BIOS) anyway so problem solved because it was never a problem. There are also supervisor passwords that can be added to preventy LOCAL access but if you do that make sure to NEVER forget it.

Comment: I think OPs concerned about how software could be used from the OS, from the interactive remote session. Firmware update utilities, for instance. I believe an Administrator Password in the firmware should work, I just don't know for certain as I've never applied or tested such a config with this in mind.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Aren't there utilities n such that can do that? I mean if Windows Update can do it, I'd assume a user could if they had enough knowledge. My main concern of course is someone flashing a compromised BOIS to the system.

Comment: @Vandel212 - Windows Update can only stage the update.  As the Administrator you would simply never deploy an update that can change the firmware. Why are you allowing non-Administrator users to install updates and software? Sounds like you need to use WSUS

Comment: @Ramhound The idea is to rent out the computer for users to do high performance computing. So they'll have an admin account on the machine, and they can install any software they'd like to complete their tasks.

Comment: @Vandel212 - If you are going to allow an Administrator install any software then you won't be able to prevent them from installing any Windows Update, since they could in theory, just download the update from the WU catalog.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It depends on the remote access provided.  For example, remote KVM, they surely can access the BIOS or UEFI.  Even without that, Windows itself can interact with UEFI, so the possibility to use a utility to modify or install a new versions also exists.

Comment: @Ramhound The question was about BIOS/UEFI rather than Windows update.  OP's point, and it's valid, is that Windows Update can install BIOS or UEFI updates, so why couldn't an admin user?

Comment: @DubStep - The author has properly brought up the fact, UEFI firmware, can and indeed can be downloaded through Windows Update although nearly always it's an seeker update due to the potential.  In that case, an Administrator, would and does have the capability to install it and there is virtual nothing the author could do about it except NOT give them Administrator permissions.

Comment: @Ramhound They could password the firmware.  Then it still needs a password to be interacted with, even via Windows update.

Comment: @DubStep - Firmware updates released through Windows Update can be installed even with a password. The firmware update is staged within Windows and applies when the system reboots

Comment: @Ramhound In my experiences doing this, Windows prompted me for the password prior to reboot.

Comment: @DubStep - I have never been required to provide a Windows password to install a firmware update through Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound Not a Windows password, the system password, which is set outside of Windows and totally independent of Windows as it's set on the motherboard software.  Nothing I've found from Microsoft says that Windows Update can bypass the system password, which would be a pretty critical security hole if it could, because if Windows can, that's an attack vector waiting to be exploited.

Answer (score 4):

As someone else pointed out in the comments, remote users will not be able to access the BIOS or UEFI, however if you want to make sure there is no local access there are solutions.

From the [ASUS WRX80e-sage manual](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/workstation/pro-ws-wrx80e-sage-se-wifi/helpdesk_manual/?model2Name=Pro-WS-WRX80E-SAGE-SE-WIFI):

## Security

The security menu items allow you to change the system security settings:
[image]

- If you forgotten your BIOS password erase the CMOS real-time clock Ram to clear the BIOS password see the motherboard for more information on how to erase the RTC Ram via the clear CMOS jumper.
- The administrator or user password items on top of the screen show the default **[not installed]** after you set a password these items show **[installed]**.

## Administrator Password

If you have set an administrator password, we recommend that you enter the administrator password for accessing the system. Otherwise, you might be able to see or change only selected fields in the BIOS setup program.

**To set an administrator password:**

1. Select the 'Administrator Password' item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. From the 'Create New Password' box, key in a password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Re-type to confirm the password then select 'OK'.

**To change an administrator password:**

1. Select the 'Administrator Password' item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. From the 'Enter Current Password' box, key in the current password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. From the 'Create New Password' box, key in a new password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Re-type to confirm the password then select 'OK'.
   To clear the administrator password, follow the same steps as in changing an administrator password, but leave other fields blank then select 'OK' to continue. After you clear the password, the 'Administrator Password' item on top of the screen shows **[Not Installed]**.

## User Password

If you have set a user password, you must enter the user password for accessing the system. The User Password item on top of the screen shows the default [Not Installed].
After you set a password, this item shows **[Installed]**.

**To set a user password:**

1. Select the 'User Password' item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. From the 'Create New Password' box, key in a password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Re-type to confirm the password then select 'OK'.

**To change a user password:**

1. Select the 'User Password' item and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. From the 'Enter Current Password' box, key in the current password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. From the 'Create New Password' box, key in a new password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Re-type to confirm the password then select 'OK'.
   To clear the user password, follow the same steps as in changing a user password, but leave other fields blank then select 'OK' to continue. After you clear the password, the 'User Password' item on top of the screen shows **[Not Installed]**.

Comment: I believe this is the answer.  I personally haven't come across a BIOS or UEFI in the past 20 years that did not have a password protection option.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not concerned about local access as I'm the only one who will be near the computer. My concern is users running a utility from within Windows that would alter the BIOS. It sounds like I have no need to be concerned about this?

Comment: @Vandel212 As the answer states, people can not remotely access your BIOS. If this satisfies your question, please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Hmmm perhaps I'm not explaining my thoughts well. I'm not worried about people "directly" accessing the BIOS via a remote connection. I'm worried about someone running software on Windows that changes the BIOS in some fashion. Such as flashing the BIOS with one that has some sort of malware on it. Does that make sense, or am I being paranoid? I feel like I remember seeing utilities that can update a system BIOS by running a utility before.

Comment: @Vandel212 you said *"I'm not concerned about local access as I'm the only one who will be near the computer."*, and its been established that remote access is impossible. My answer addresses both those concerns.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Ok, I'm not trying to be difficult, I just wanted to be 100% clear on that, as this is incredibly important to me. It sounded like you were only saying that users couldn't connect remotely and navigate through the BIOS and change settings like they were standing in front of the machine which was never a concern of mine. My concern was the user executing some program while in the OS and then it somehow flashes the BIOS with a compromised version, either while running or during a restart. Does that make sense?

Comment: In most cases, flashing the BIOS firmware won't remove a BIOS password. The BIOS password is typically stored in a non-volatile memory location on the motherboard, which is separate from the BIOS firmware. So unless there is someone who can physically access the machine, bypassing the password is unlikely.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid This has to be me, I have to be explaining it poorly. I'm afraid of someone flashing a compromised BIOS to the the system via a utility in the OS. I'm not worried about the password, or anyone booping around the BIOS changing settings. Is this something I need to be worried about? If so, is there a way to prevent it from outside the OS.

Comment: @Vandel212 Keep worrying all you like. I have no more time, energy or inclination to keep saying the same thing over and over.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I get the impression you are annoyed, I apologize. I'm really not trying to be an ass or dumb. It's just that when I read your explanations it just keeps sounding like you are addressing only the possibility of people remotely accessing the BIOS like they were standing in front of the computer or removing the password. Lets make this simple, is it possible for someone to execute a program on Windows and have it mess with the BIOS in any shape or form if I set the password? Yes, or no. Feel free to ignore this comment I'd understand.

Comment: I agree that this is not the answer and remote admin users can update the bios.  Would it be sufficient to monitor the bios and have an action, such as an alarm, trigger if the bios changes?

Comment: @aqf At a minimum yes, obviously preventing it entirely would be ideal. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a lot of misinformation in these comments. The BIOS can be modified remotely, as well as from within windows. Also, the BIOS password is stored on the same EEPROM as the firmware, and updating the BIOS definately can remove BIOS passwords on some systems. Sometimes as simple as a commandline switch on the BIOS update utility which runs from Windows. -- I used to own a computer repair shop and cleared passwords in exactly that way, and remotely as well.